# How to use cout to print selected parts of a string

Tags: c++

This was a question given to me by my friend who is taking computer programming in college.

Try to write another program using only cout 
statements to print the initial of your last name in 
large letters using only *.

```
cout <<” * “ << endl;
cout <<” * * “ << endl;
cout <<
```

they use of course though the conio i've never used before.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
```

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
// Last name Astari  =>initial of your last name is "A"

std::cout <<  "   **   \n";
std::cout <<  "  *  *  \n";
std::cout <<  "  ****  \n";
std::cout <<  "  ****  \n";
std::cout <<  "  *  *  \n";
```

Comment: wow... really..I thought it was a shortcut for something :/ Thats simple thanks lol